# How to add new line in html between h1 and h2

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to HTML and I am trying to add a new line between h1 and h2, here is the code

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'mainFont';
  src: url("Fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Medium.ttf") format('truetype');
}

body {
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.main {
  font-family: 'mainFont';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #181818;
}

.subMain {
  font-family: 'mainFont';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #181818;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class='main'>Hello World </h1>
  <h2 class='subMain'> I'm a Game Developer</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

I've tried stuff like `br` but they don't at all work and I get a result something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGv1J.png)

Comment: You've made your `<body>` tag a flex row. That means you intend for the contents of it to be in a horizontal row. Either change it to a flex column, or else why does it have to be a flex? Leave that out and you'll get the behaviour you're expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flexbox makes your elements displayed horizontally. You just need to remove `display:flex` on `body` styles that will help you to break it into 2 lines as usual.

`h1` and `h2` have their own default margin which makes a huge gap between them. To remove the margin gap between `h1` and `h2`, you need to set `margin` like below

```
h2, h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'mainFont';
  src: url("Fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Medium.ttf") format('truetype');
}

body {
  height: 90vh;
  /* display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; */
  text-align: center;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.main {
  font-family: 'mainFont';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #181818;
}

.subMain {
  font-family: 'mainFont';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #181818;
}

/*Override default margin of h1 and h2*/
h2, h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class='main'>Hello World </h1>
  <h2 class='subMain'> I'm a Game Developer</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

Another approach for your case is adding another element in between of `body` and your content. In that situation, you don't need to modify `body` styles, all elements within additional div will be in the center by flexbox from body.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'mainFont';
  src: url("Fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Medium.ttf") format('truetype');
}

body {
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.main {
  font-family: 'mainFont';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #181818;
}

.subMain {
  font-family: 'mainFont';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #181818;
}

h2, h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
     <h1 class='main'>Hello World </h1>
  <h2 class='subMain'> I'm a Game Developer</h2>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It works but it puts a huge gap between the texts

Comment: Because `h1` and `h2` have `margin` as their natures in HTML. You need to set margin 0 for them to remove that margin gap. I updated that in my answer too, you can check it out @Saharsh

Comment: another thing is that it's not really centered and the text is at the top and not at the position i want like in the middle

Comment: You mean the center of the screen? @Saharsh

Comment: yes, i mean the text is not coming on the center of the screen

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/xhdXF4q/image.png the gap has not yet gone even if i set the margin to 0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an empty space you can use: `<br>`
If you want to put a line you should use `<hr>`

You can then style the style with css.

Comment: So where should i add br or hr?

Comment: could you just send me the code or tell me where to add them specifically?

Comment: <h1 class='main'>Hello World </h1>
<br>
<h2 class='subMain'> I'm a Game Developer</h2>

Comment: But it is also not a good advice to use flex on .body class

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Juste add `<br>` balise

```html
<h1 class='main'>Hello World </h1>
<br>
<h2 class='subMain'> I'm a Game Developer</h2>
```

And change your body css to this:

```css
body {
  height: 90vh;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: `</br>` is a typo, you probably meant `<br>` (or, if you’re recommending XML/XHTML for some reason, `<br />`).

Comment: Indeed a typing error on my part ... the answer is corrected.